# WPF MVVM two views, one view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I am writing an application, which supposed to be running on 2 monitors, 
when then small monitor displays the light version of the same information displayed on the large one.

What is the best way to implement this using MVVM model?

I have thought to create one view model and two views, and set the datacontext of those views to be the view model. Is it a right way to implement this ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm nowhere near being an MVVM expert, but to me your solution looks correct.

Comment: you may share some code, may someone point out if something necessary is missing.

Comment: There is no code yet.
I am in the planning stage now.

Comment: "Is it a right way to implement this?" Yes, it is. One reason for separating into view and view model is that you can easily replace the view while keeping the view model.

Comment: Viewmodels don't care about views so if a vm supports 10 different views then there is no reason not to use it. If you're worried about it, an alternative would be to implement a message interface between two viewmodels, such as mvvm light. Just make sure your binding to the same instance of the viewmodel.

Comment: I would do the same as you are planning.

Comment: I do not think that it is the right way. Despite possible performance problems when having two views to care about, there are other ways to get you application running. What resolutions do you expect? What is the data to display like?

Answer (score 1):

> I have thought to create one view model and two views, and set the
>   datacontext of those views to be the view model. Is it a right way to
>   implement this ?

As a comment a above stated, VM doesn't care about how it is used, so you can use 1 VM as View's DataContext as many as you want to.